# Cruisecontrol.net & Visual SVN port issue

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn-server

I seem to have a strange issues with cruisecontrol.net (ver 1.6.7). My VisualSVN Server port is set to 8443, and this has been working fine.

However the cruisecontrol.net is failing to connect to VisualSVN Server instance.

The following sourcecontrol extract from my ccnet.config is what is failing:

```
 <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <authCaching>Always</authCaching>     
      <executable>C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <trunkUrl>https://svn.aaaa.org:8443/svn/wim-web/Year%20Round%20Site/Trunk</trunkUrl>
      <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
      <username>rrrrr</username>
      <password>xxxxx</password>
      <workingDirectory>D:\CCNET\Builds\Web\YearRoundSite</workingDirectory>
 </sourcecontrol>
```

The error message that I get back refers to  https://svn.aaaa.org without the port specified (8443). Without the port specified this goes to a website not a SVN repository and so fails to connect.

Comment: Please post the intresting part of the ccnet debug log file.

Comment: What error it is showing? Can you try to do a manual checkout using the same svn url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the CC.NET machine.  Login as the same account(identity) that runs the CC.NET SERVICE.  (<

At the commandline..........run a svn.exe list command

```
svn list https://svn.aaaa.org:8443/svn/wim-web/Year%20Round%20Site/Trunk
```

(You'll have to find the full path for your svn.exe of course)

(or something like that)

See if you get prompted to accept a certificate.  If so, select (p) for permanent.

Now re-try.

I've found you have to command-line accept the certificate before CC.NET-SVN will work.

Comment: I have done the above. The problem is that in the log xml file the paramter is incorrect:  <CCNetProjectUrl>https://svn.aaaa.org/svn/wim-web/Year%20Round%20Site/Trunk</CCNetProjectUrl>  It refers to an old url that does not include the port 8443 number and hence cannot connect. Any idea where/how the <CCNetProjectUrl> paramter is set?

Comment: Are you pulling a different MSbuild file or something....another place that URL might be set?  Aka, are you absolutely positive the only place you're setting the property is with the <trunkUrl> value?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the TrunkURL if you specify the working directory. 
You first have to manually go to your working directory and use SVN to do the initial checkout. Then the SVN that cruise control runs will know how to contact the repository for that working directory.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by doing a checkout? The SVN and CCNet server are on a server. I have no problems checking in and out using TortoiseSVN from client PC's.

Comment: `cd` to the folder `D:\CCNET\Builds\Web\YearRoundSite` then do an `SVN -co` command. Then you don't need to specify the trunk URL in your config. It is possible that at one point you checked out the source from the old URL into that working directory. That is where SVN is getting the bad URL.

Comment: Thanks for your response when I run that command on the server I get the following: D:\CCNET\Builds\Web\YearRoundSite>SVN -co svn: Non-numeric change argument (o) given to -c

Comment: sorry, no dash. It is `svn co https://svn.aaaa.org:8443/svn/wim-web/Year%20Round%20Site/Trunk .`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed your advice, the error on the url again does not include Port Number, and

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am now back to the original error, where the port number is dropped from the error message. There is a different certificate for both https://svn.aaaa.org (which is an IIS site) and https://svn.aaaa.org:8433 (SVN)> Error message is:

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.aaaa.org/svn/wim-web/Year%20Round%20Site/Trunk': Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted (https://svn.aaaa.org)